# How to replace "pause" Command words with my own words?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I am running the following program,

```
@echo off
cls
echo.
echo Press any key and have fun..
pause
```

I am getting output as,

```
Press any key and have fun..
Press any key to continue . . .
```

But, my need is only first line from above output. I want to hide or replace the second line. Pls help.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552648/suppress-the-press-any-key-to-continue-in-batch-script

Comment: Thank u soo much it works. `pause>nul`